# Outdoors in the winter

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the feeling of longing coziness you get when you are outdoors during the winter and you look inside a house with the lights on?

Comment: Neologisms are off topic here, otherwise I would say 'hearthsick'.

Comment: If you are comfortable outdoors in winter, you generally don’t want to go back inside. So **resignation** might be the best word. It’s the feeling you have in returning from the ski slope or the hockey rink, and seeing that others have already packed it in, and you have to join them.

Comment: @Nigel I don't suppose one off topic neologism is more valid than another, but I would say "hearthstruck."

Comment: err  ...  envious

Answer (score 1):

There is a Danish word called 'hygge' which refers to "a form of everyday togetherness". The noun hygge includes something nice, cosy, safe and known, referring to a psychological state.

Comment: Do you have a link to *hygge* defined as an **English** word?

Comment: Chi, Du, Ger, Nor, Swed, Jap .... alas no english!

Comment: @lbf Yeah there are, en.oxforddictionaries.com and Wikipedia

Comment: @Zebrafish as an English word?

Comment: @lbf Yeah, strange, en.oxforddictionaries.com added it, but admittedly no other dictionary has it from the quick search I did Wikipedia has an article on it in English. And it's kind of one of those foreign cultural terms that, you know, spread, or metastasise, depending how you feel about it.

Comment: @lbf it was on one of the major dictionary publisher's annual lists of interesting new words within the last couple of years. Presumably Oxford's going by Zebrafish's comment.

Comment: You might be surprised how much of English is 'borrowed' from other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Since the questions references "a house" it would seem a word to describe the person looking might be 'voyeur'. };') (Ah, c'mon, can't we have a little fun?)

Comment: Seriously though, the first word which comes to mind is 'melancholy'.